# Lightweight ubuntu GUI for 18.04? Only have 16MB onboard graphics card

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, motherboard, ubuntu-18.04

I have an X8SIL-F motherboard which comes with a very small onboard 16MB graphics card.

For stability reasons which I won't go into, I updated my system from 16.04 to 18.04 but now 16MB is not enough to really power the default GUI (not sure what it's called) I used to have Mint for 16.04.

But maybe it's what kind of monitor I'm using? I'm using my 1080p TV by way of a VGA to HDMI converter. I need help because this goes beyond what I know of computers (very DIY and not uber-savy).

Which will solve my problem of slow GUI, switching to a smaller/low-res monitor or find a weird x8 PCIe graphics card for the motherboard? Or is there a known lighter GUI out there that won't run so slow?

I'm really only using this system to run my Plex. I very rarely use the GUI, but sometimes I need to, so I don't want to switch to full text mode. Otherwise this is just an always-on system with an always-off monitor.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using SSH with X11 forwarding?

Comment: @MMM I am familiar with SSH and sometimes I SSH insto my system, but I'm not familiar with X11 forwarding or how it relates to SSH, I will google it maybe.

Comment: Would Lubuntu be a better choice?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I like the sound of this, but I'm not certain it would run the few programs I do need/still want to use on it. Also, because of the fragile state of my system and being unable to perform a system backup, I would be nervous to convert to another OS.

Comment: @MaggieS., you don't have to change over to test another OS such as Lubuntu: run the OS from a Live install on USB - no change to your HDD. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/138845/can-i-create-a-liveusb-for-installing-lubuntu-without-using-a-cd

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks, I'll give this another look-see then.